# Redirecting the InstallShield log to console

Tags: installshield

I'm using the InstallShield 2011 Automation Interface to create my installer. During the build log files are generated in the MSI_English\LogFiles folder.

Is it possible to redirect the log to the console. This would be more convenient for my build server.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer may be to use `iscmdbld.exe` instead of the automation interface. This already sends messages to the console.

The more complex answer should be to [use build status events](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield21helplib/helplibrary/AutomationBuildStatEv.htm) (its VB sample is excerpted below). In particular you will want to handle the `StatusMessage` event. Note that you'll want to change the instances of `21` to match the version of the rest of your automation script.

```
Public WithEvents pISWiRelease As ISWiAuto21.ISWiRelease

Private Sub Foo()
    Dim pISWiProject As IswiAuto21.ISWiProject
    Set pISWiProject = CreateObject("IswiAuto21.ISWiProject")
    pISWiProject.OpenProject "C:\InstallShield 2014 Projects\My Project Name-1.ism", False
    Set pISWiRelease = pISWiProject21.ISWiProductConfigs("Product Configuration 1").ISWiReleases("Release 1")
    pISWiRelease.Build
    pISWiProject.CloseProject
    Set pISWiRelease = Nothing
    Set pISWiProject = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub pISWiRelease_ProgressIncrement(ByVal lIncrement As Long, pbCancel As Boolean)
    ' Place your code here
End Sub

Private Sub pISWiRelease_ProgressMax(ByVal lMax As Long, pbCancel As Boolean)
    ' Place your code here
End Sub

Private Sub pISWiRelease_StatusMessage(ByVal sMessage As String, pbCancel As Boolean)
    ' Place your code here
End Sub
```

Comment: Any suggestions on how this would work with JScript? Not getting where it registers as an event observer - but thats likely my lack of experience with VB.

Comment: In the VB example, it's magic involving the leading `WithEvents` line. In C++ the overall technique is called Connection Points. In C# it's events and delegates. Some searches suggest it might turn into `attachEvent` or `addEventListener` in JScript (something like `pISWiRelease.attachEvent("StatusMessage", f)`), but I'm unfamiliar with exactly how to do this. Hopefully that's at least good keywords for your searches!